# protobuf-net closing tcpclient

Tags: .net, sockets, protobuf-net

I am writing a client server application that is using protobuf for serialisation, and a TCPClient / TCPListener for transfering the data.

The application has been written to send a message from client to sever, which the sever then sends a response back. It is then due to sleep for 2 seconds, and repeat.

Everything is working fine for the first cycle, but when it tries again the second time, it generates an exception that the socket is closed.

I thought by using SerializeWithLengthPrefix / DeserializeWithLengthPrefix that this kept the socket open?

Full code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SocketServer
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Message
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartAcceptor();

            StartClient();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void StartAcceptor()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
                {
                    var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8888);
                    serverSocket.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Server >> Started");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        var clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                        Console.WriteLine("Server >> Client Connected");
                        StartServerSocket(clientSocket);
                    }
                });
        }

        static void StartServerSocket(TcpClient clientSocket)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
                {
                    while ((true))
                    {
                        using (NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream())
                        {
                            var message = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Message>(networkStream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
                            Console.WriteLine(message.Content);

                            message.Content += " Received";
                            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(networkStream, message, PrefixStyle.Base128);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        static void StartClient()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
                {
                    var client = new TcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Client >> Started");
                    client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client >> Connected To Server");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();

                        var message = new Message();
                        message.Content = "Hello";

                        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(serverStream, message, PrefixStyle.Base128);

                        var messager = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Message>(serverStream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
                        Console.WriteLine(messager.Content);

                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is you that is closing the socket. Restructure:

```
while(...)
    using(...)
        {...}
```

To:

```
using(...)
    while(...)
        {...}
```

At the moment, it it the end of the using block in the first iteration that closes the socket.